# Testing code in a window.addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, mocking

I have the following `angularjs` based component which works fine, but looking at test coverage anything after `window.addEventListener('message',` is not covered.

Should I mock the `window` object and provide my own implementation for `addEventListener`? or spy on it and check its been called?

my.component.controller.ts

```
export class MyComponentController {
  constructor() {}

  public theEventOccurred(e: any) {
    let json = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(json.document);
  }

  public $onInit() {
    window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
      this.theEventOccurred(event);
    }, false);
  }
}
```

my.component.spec.ts

```
describe('Component: my', () => {

  let $componentController: angular.IComponentControllerService;
  let scope: angular.IScope;

  beforeEach(inject(
    ($rootScope: angular.IScope,
      _$componentController_: angular.IComponentControllerService) => {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      $componentController = _$componentController_;
    }));

  describe('Controller: MyComponentController', () => {
    it('should log json.document', () => {
      let ctrl: any = $componentController('my', { $scope: scope });
      ctrl.$onInit();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Whatever you are doing with message events should be packaged into a service and tested separately. Component controllers should only be concerned with the logic relevant to rendering the component view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good pattern to access directly `window` or `document` object from the component code.

The better way, as I see, is to put `window` in a separate service and then just use a dependency injection to put the service into component.

Check [this](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/) for example.

Then you can spy the methods of the service, or just inject a mock service in your tests.